# What can it be tfs 2015 Builds stoped working

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfs-2015

I working with TFS2015,
today I tried to run the build as usual but i stuck with unknown issue
what happens :
after running the build (using WebUI VNext build definition)
as usual console screen appears and writes 
Waiting for console output from an agent .. and after a couple seconds throws build failed without exceptions.

i didn't change anything on the servers, what can it be ? (maybe last windows update win server 2012 R2)

**tried:**

- Use another user for the agent connection
- Register the agent again.

**getting the same exception:**

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden
...
##[error]The Agent failed to start this job. Error: Forbidden
```

in the log trace i see (maybe is it something that I should care ? ):

```
07:36:44.597025 ConsoleTimer_Callback - Inside Lock
```

How can I do a deeper search for the problem? Can fiddler/wireshark help me to debug the forbidden reason (source-destination ?)

Comment: You should probably add at least an extract from the TFS build log here.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt - that is the issue that is no log ?! it's empty (tried to see if the problem is in the network connection or application user seems to be fine)

Comment: Have you checked the logs on the agent? Should be in the agent's installation folder under `_diag`. Upgrading to Azure DevOps Server is also highly recommended, TFS2015 was very much a v1 of the new agent infra and a LOT of fixes have gone into later versions.

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden (seems like authentication ..)

Comment: the application user is currently on windows service and iis .. where could be the problem?

Comment: Deregister the agent and register again.

Comment: @jessehouwing tried nothing happened still Forbidden.. ##[error]The Agent failed to start this job. Error: Forbidden

Comment: @jessehouwing How can I debug the net request to see where exactly its happens ?

Comment: @jessehouwing tried wireshark says 403 authorization error but where it can be (the agent/iis) given i even maked that user admin for now to test and nothing

Comment: The user that RUNS the agent isn't the user the agent uses to authenticate to Azure DevOps Server. In the registration process, you specify the user that does the running oof the jobs. The server must also be configured to accept NTLM + Basic Auth for the agent to be able to communicate. A OAuth Token is used to run the builds. Docs on the auth process: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/design/auth.md

Agents are granted permission through the `Project Collection Build Service Accounts` group.